# Realizar um único click onclick

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, como disparar o método com um clique na TR?

segue código

```
<script> 
function exibe(id) {  
    var display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
    if( display === "none") {  
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "inline";  
    } else {  
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";  
    }     
}
</script>

<h1 class="musc"> Músculos </h1>
<table id="musc">
    <tr onclick="exibe('localdador');"> 
        <td class="ce"> 
            <input type="radio" name="tMusculos" id="c17" value="Imagem 1" onClick="mudarimagem(1)"> 
        </td> 
        <td class="cd"> 
            <label for="c17"> Anterior </label> 
        </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: onclick em php não existe, isso é javascript, reformule a pergunta e coloque o que você quer fazer com o click, não da pra entender o que você precisa

Comment: Seu código está incompleto  além de conter erros, falta a função `mudarimagem(i)` falta a tag image, quem é essa variavel `id` de `getElementById(id)`

Comment: Esse único click seria em que elemento? input radio ou na tr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse seu caso, marcando `input radio`, evidentemente, estás clicando na `tr` que contém o `input` e consequentemente as duas funções serão executadas,
porém a reciproca não é verdadeira, isto é, ao clicar na `tr` somente a função inerente a `tr` será disparada. Veja no exemplo a seguir:

```js
function mudarimagem(i) {    
    if (i == 1) {
        document.getElementById("imagem").src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IncM.jpg";
    } else {            
     document.getElementById("imagem").src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj325.jpg";    
    }
}

function exibe(id) {  
   var display = document.getElementById('id').style.display;
   if( display === "none") {  
      document.getElementById('id').style.display = "inline";  
   } else {  
      document.getElementById('id').style.display = "none";  
   }     
}
```

```html
<h1 id="id" class="musc"> Músculos </h1>   
   <table id="musc" border="0" width="200" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" height="100" style="border-collapse: collapse">
      <tr onclick="exibe('localdador');"> 
         <td class="ce"> <input type="radio" name="tMusculos" id="c17" value="Imagem 1" onclick="mudarimagem(1);"> </td> 
         <td class="cd"> <label for="c17"> Anterior </label> </td> 
      </tr> 
  </table>
  
  <img id="imagem" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj325.jpg">
```

Existem algumas formas para executar as duas funções com um clique apenas.

Chame uma função dentro da outra função, dessa forma, quando chamar uma automaticamente chamará a outra.

> function exibe(id) {
>      mudarimagem(1);

Exemplo:

```js
function mudarimagem(i) {    
 if (i == 1) {
        document.getElementById("imagem").src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IncM.jpg";
    } else {            
     document.getElementById("imagem").src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj325.jpg";    
    }
}

function exibe(id) {  
   mudarimagem(1);
   var display = document.getElementById('id').style.display;
   if( display === "none") {  
      document.getElementById('id').style.display = "inline";  
   }    
    else {  
      document.getElementById('id').style.display = "none";  
   }     
}
```

```html
<h1 id="id" class="musc"> Músculos </h1>   
   <table id="musc" border="0" width="200" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" height="100" style="border-collapse: collapse">
      <tr onclick="exibe('localdador');"> 
         <td class="ce"> <input type="radio" name="tMusculos" id="c17" value="Imagem 1"> </td> 
         <td class="cd"> <label for="c17"> Anterior </label> </td> 
      </tr> 
  </table>
  
  <img id="imagem" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj325.jpg">
```

> outra forma seria separar as funções por **;** (ponto e virgula) em um único evento `onclick`: `<tr onclick="exibe('localdador'); mudarimagem(1);">`

Outra solução seria passar uma função que chame as duas:

```
<tr onclick="executar();">
```

e

```
function executar(){
    exibe('localdador');
    mudarimagem(1);
}
```